# React Rails "identifier 'Set' undefined"

Tags: react-rails, webpacker

I am trying to do server side rendering with rails using webpacker & react-rails. I don't have any problem with client-side rendering but I got the following exception with server-side rendering.

```
ExecJS::ProgramError in Static#index

identifier 'Set' undefined
```

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>ReactExample</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.html.erb

```
<%= react_component('hello', {}, {prerender: true}) %>
```

application.js

```
/* eslint no-console:0 */
// This file is automatically compiled by Webpack, along with any other files
// present in this directory. You're encouraged to place your actual application logic in
// a relevant structure within app/javascript and only use these pack files to reference
// that code so it'll be compiled.
//
// To reference this file, add <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %> to the appropriate
// layout file, like app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

// Support component names relative to this directory:
var componentRequireContext = require.context("components", true)
var ReactRailsUJS = require("react_ujs")
ReactRailsUJS.useContext(componentRequireContext)
```

server_rendering.js

```
// By default, this pack is loaded for server-side rendering.
// It must expose react_ujs as `ReactRailsUJS` and prepare a require context.
var componentRequireContext = require.context("components", true)
var ReactRailsUJS = require("react_ujs")
ReactRailsUJS.useContext(componentRequireContext)
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade from TheRubyRacer to a JavaScript execution engine that is modern.

TheRubyRacer depends on LibV8 (the bit that powers node.js) but it's [locked to version 3](https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer/blob/v0.12.3/therubyracer.gemspec#L20), LibV8 itself is already at [version 7](https://github.com/cowboyd/libv8/releases/tag/v7.3.492.27.1).

Use a modern JS gem such as [Mini_Racer](https://github.com/discourse/mini_racer) and this issue goes away.